# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' - Text Based interactive story in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I am trying to make a text-based interactive story in python, but I keep getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

My code is quite long, so I will post a part of the story that gets this error:

```
approach = {'sceneText': "Following the map from the old man in the tavern, you arrive at a large hill,"
                        "covered with ancient standing stone forming the shape of a skull if viewed from a high vantage "
                        "point.", \

    'choices': ["Enter the Tomb of Horrors!", "Run Away! (Wuss)"], 'nextScene':["Entrance", "Runaway"]}
def main():
    story = {"Approach":approach, "Runaway":runaway, "Entrance":entrance, "Sealed":sealed, "Collapse":collapse, "Hallway":hallway, "Demon":demon, "PurpleHaze":purplehaze, "Damn":damn, "PitTrap":pittrap, "Gargoyle":gargoyle, "MoreSpikes":morespikes}
    sceneData = story['Approach']

    while(True):
        #.get metehod returns value for the given key
        print(sceneData.get('sceneText'))
        print("Choices: ")
        for choice in sceneData.get('choices'):
            print(choice)
        user_choice = input("Select a choice: ")
        sceneData = story.get(user_choice)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When ran:

```
Following the map from the old man in the tavern, you arrive at a large hill,covered with ancient standing stone forming the shape of a skull if viewed from a high vantage point.
Choices: 
Enter the Tomb of Horrors!
Run Away! (Wuss)
Select a choice: Enter the Tomb of Horrors!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "story.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "story.py", line 67, in main
    print(sceneData.get('sceneText'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you reassign screenData based on the user input (`sceneData = story.get(user_choice)`) you're not ensuring that you've entered something valid.  If they put in something you don't have screenData for, you'll return `None` from the `.get()` call there, and then when you attempt to access `screenData[screenText]` you get the `NoneType` error.

Comment: So how would I make it so if the user enters one of the choices it would accept it and go on to the next scene?

Comment: You can test for whether they made a valid selection using `user_choice in sceneData`, or you can provide a default scene via `sceneData.get(user_choice, <default>)`.  Which you use depends on how you want the flow of your program to operate.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers mentioned, you are referencing a non-existent key within `story` which is why it's giving you an error.  In short, this is how your code is currently running:

```
# Iteration 1 
print(sceneData.get('sceneText'))
# evals to approach.get('sceneText'))
# prints flavour text

print("Choices: ")
for choice in sceneData.get('choices'):
    # evals to approach.get('choices')
    print(choice)
    # print list of choices within approach dict

user_choice = input("Select a choice: ")

# user inputs "Enter the Tomb..."
sceneData = story.get(user_choice)
# evals to sceneData = story.get("Enter the Tomb...")
# Since story does not have an "Enter the Tomb" key, it returns None by default.
# sceneData = None

# ---

# Iteration 2
print(sceneData.get('sceneText'))
# evals to None.get('sceneText'))
# errors out
```

There's two key issues in your code structure:

1. You're not validating the input.  i.e. If user inputted "Exit" it'll crash all the same.  You should have at least a basic check like this:

   ```
   while True:
       user_choice = input("Select a choice: ")
       if user_choice in sceneData.get('choices'): break
       print('That was an invalid choice, try again.')
   ```
2. You're not really doing anything with the choices inputted.  There's nothing that contains a key `"Enter the Tomb..."` within your code and it's bounded to fail with a `.get("Enter the Tomb...")` method.

You can either reference the `index` of choices within your `approach` dict and get the `nextScene` (which is a bit more work):

```
scene_index = sceneData.get('choices').index(user_choice)
sceneData = story.get('nextScene')[scene_index]
```

Or you can restructure your code so that the `choices` are `dicts` like so:

```
approach = {...    
    'choices': {
        "Enter the Tomb of Horrors!": "Entrance", 
        "Run Away! (Wuss)": "Runaway"
    }
}
```

And when needing the `choices`, call it with:

```
sceneData.get('choices').keys()
```

When needing the `nextScene`, call it with:

```
sceneData = story.get(sceneData.get('choices').get(user_choice))
```

There are lots of ways to tackle this.  It's up to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you assign nothing because there is no key in there that matches either one of the choices provided, effectively setting `sceneData` to `None`

Then, on the next loop iteration, the `print(sceneData.get('choices')` errors out because sceneData is now `None`, and no longer a `dict`.

`story.get(user_choice)`

This references the `story` dict:

```
story = {
    "Approach":approach, "Runaway":runaway, 
    "Entrance":entrance, "Sealed":sealed, 
    "Collapse":collapse, "Hallway":hallway, 
    "Demon":demon, "PurpleHaze":purplehaze, 
    "Damn":damn, "PitTrap":pittrap, 
    "Gargoyle":gargoyle, "MoreSpikes":morespikes
}
```

As you can see, there is no key in `story` that matches either of your `choices` list values.

*You might want to map a number of the choice to the next scene;*

For example

```
choices: {
    1: { 'choice-text': 'Enter the Tomb of Horrors!, 'nextScene': 'someScene' }
}
```

And then have the user input the number of the choice, and write some code that will set the next scene based on the `nextScene` key.